# Sorting 2d vector passed by reference

Tags: c++, sorting, multidimensional-array, vector

I implemented Prim's algorithm. It returns a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` (which is a vector of vectors : [vertice, vertice, weight]). The results are correct, but when I compare it with my lab guys results, sometimes there is a difference like:

I have an edge `4-1` with weight 2, and he has an edge `1-4` with weight 2 + his results are like `0-something`, `0-something`, `1-something`, `2-something`, and mine are `4-something`, `1-something`, `2-something`.

I know that it's not an error but he is soo much nitpicking, so I thought I will sort this vector.

First of all I would sort inner vector by swapping those 2 vertice labels if the [0] one is bigger than the [1] one.

Then I would sort them all by checking if [0] in some vector is bigger than [0] in other vector. I've got this code:

```
void undirected_graph::mySort(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& input)
{
    for (auto row = input.begin(); row != input.end(); ++row)
    {
        if (row[0] > row[1])
        {
            std::swap(row[0], row[1]);
        }
    }

    std::sort(input.begin(), input.end(), [](const std::vector< int >& a, const std::vector< int >& b) { return a[0] < b[0]; });
}
```

I call that method with `mySort(mst)` (which is of type `std:vector<std::vector<int>>`)

The error when it attemtps to `std::swap` I get is: `vector iterator not dereferencable`

Should I pass the vector somehow different, or should I change something in this method code?

Comment: Are you trying to sort each inner vector and then put the inner vectors in sorted order too?

Comment: I'm surprised that `row[0]` compiles at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto row` is an iterator. That iterator's `operator[]` does not call the according operator on the pointed-to element but returns the element that the iterator would point to if it were incremented by the given operand. Hence, the statement `row[1]` may try to dereference the `end()` iterator of the vector, which is not possible. What you want to do is this:

```
if ((*row)[0] > (*row)[1])
{
    std::swap((*row)[0], (*row)[1]);
}
```

You should also write your comparison predicate in a way that uses the second entry whenever the first entries are equal.

Comment: `That iterator does not have an appropriate operator[].` Random-access iterators such as `std::vector::iterator` are required to have an `operator[]`. The OP's code compiles without issue. Whether it works, I don't know.

Comment: @DeiDei, thanks, I missed that. Corrected the answer.

Comment: You're right, that was the problem. But now the same issue happens with `std::sort`

Comment: @Frynio Are you sure? With the above modification, I can run your method just fine.